# How to fix STM32CubeProgrammer No STM32 Target Found

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, stm32cubemx

**Hello guys**

Any one here faced this problem before ? 

After I run my code into my stm32f446re I couldn't upload any code after my last code and give me this error " No STM32 Target Found "

[image]

I tried to do these options :- 

1- Update my ST-Link driver and run it as "dpinst_amd64".

2- Update my ST-Link firmware , It's was ran and updated it from STM32CubeProgrammer as in photo.

but Doesn't work any of those solution.

Comment: what if you reset or power on with the boot0 pin toggled to put it in the bootloader, maybe your application has crashed the chip.

Comment: application cant crash or brick the chip

Comment: try connect "under reset". probably you just changed the role of the SWD pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used Stm32 St-Link Utility to solve this problem. 

I connect with the board with "connect under reset" after that I did "full chip erase" option. 
[image]

Answer (score 11):

1. First connect your board
2. Click to Refresh on Right Hand Side of STM32CubeProgrammer
3. First Select ST-Link for connecting from drop-down above ST-Link Configuration.
4. The set the configuration as:

   ```
   Port : SWD
   Mode : Normal
   Reset Mode : Normal
   ```
5. Then Press the reset and hold it and click "Connect" button. And just after pressing release the reset button. Now, your board should get connected

Comment: Minor change at some point in CubeProgrammer. I'm using V2.8.0 and ran into the same problem. But now there's no 'Normal' option for Reset mode (I'd also somehow ended up on the Software reset option). Changing to the Hardware reset option worked for me. Also using SWD and Mode = Normal.

Comment: Patch v2.8.1 still has the same problem. Hardware reset is the workaround.

Answer (score 7):

The board I am using is STM32L4S5 (b-l4s5i-iot01a)
And changing the "Reset mode" on the right-hand side to 'Hardware reset' works for me!

[image: Click on connect]

Comment: Very good, thanks for sharing.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the command line, you might also want to try:

```
STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=SWD reset=HWrst -d "<your-bin-file>" 0x08000000 -v -HardRst
```

The Hardware Reset '`reset=HWrst`' is specified as an option for "`--connect`/`-c`" in the CLI utility (see `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe --help`).

I haven't looked but the option should probably be somewhere in the STM32CubeProgrammer UI as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hello referring to my case I found the solution yesterday, many are going through the same problem as me.

What I did was just use the following pins from the SWD connector.

I used pin 2 - SWCLK, pin 3 - GND, and pin 4 - SWDIO

Pin 1 of the SWD connector is a fake 3v3, so I used pin 4 of the CN6 connector that provides 3v3.